# How to use v-model with Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How is it managed reactivity in form fields (v-model) with Vue3 Composition API? I mean, currently something simple like this doesn't work in my code > vue devtools doesn't show any changes in ref data when I rite some text in my input field:

JS

```
import { ref, watch, reactive } from 'vue';

const vueapp = Vue.createApp({

  setup(props, {attrs, slots, emit}){
    
    const test = ref('');

    return {
      test
    }
  },

});

vueapp.mount('#form-panels');
```

HTML

```
<input name="test" v-model="test" id="name" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: You should know that under the hood, in the data options API, Vue is actually using `reactive` to create its reactivity with Proxies. So, composition API only changes the way you define, for example, data, methods and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code once it should work

```
import { ref, watch, reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';

const vueapp = Vue.createApp({

  setup(props, {attrs, slots, emit}){
    
    const state = {test:''};

    return {
      ...toRefs(state)
    }
  },

});

vueapp.mount('#form-panels');
```